# How to apply HAVING to a column and not a function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, one with the names of hacking students and another with the challenges they made. I need to return the id, names and the number of challenges of the hackers, e.g:

```
hacker_id   name    challenges_created
21283       Angela      6
88255       Patrick     5
5077        Rose        4
62743       Frank       4
96196       Lisa        1
```

But if more than one hacker created the same number of challenges and that number is less that of the hacker who made the most challenges, those hackers must be excluded from the results. In this case, the 4s must be excluded. I found the exact answer for the problem online, which looks like this (edited to use my table names):

```sql
SELECT c.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.hacker_id) AS ctn
FROM Sample0.Hackers as h
    LEFT JOIN Sample0.Challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
    GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
    HAVING ctn = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(c1.challenge_id) FROM Sample0.Challenges AS c1 GROUP BY c1.hacker_id ORDER BY COUNT(*)) OR
    ctn NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(c2.challenge_id) FROM Sample0.Challenges AS c2 GROUP BY c2.hacker_id HAVING c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id);
```

I'm getting errors on the HAVING clause, saying "Invalid column name 'ctn'". I've only worked with HAVING once and can only use a basic function on it. I don't know why it's giving me this error.

Comment: Use COUNT(c.hacker_id) ... not the Alias cnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use inline alias name try like below

```
SELECT
c.hacker_id,
h.name,
COUNT(c.hacker_id) AS ctn
FROM Sample0.Hackers as h
    left JOIN Sample0.Challenges as c 
    ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
    GROUP BY c.hacker_id, h.name
     HAVING COUNT(c.hacker_id) = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(c1.challenge_id) FROM Sample0.Challenges AS c1 GROUP BY c1.hacker_id ORDER BY COUNT(*)) OR
    COUNT(c.hacker_id) NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(c2.challenge_id) FROM Sample0.Challenges AS c2 where  c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id GROUP BY c2.hacker_id )
```

And your selection column and group by column was not from same table so it thrown error hacker_id' is invalid in the HAVING clause

Comment: It gives me the error "Column 'Sample0.Challenges.hacker_id' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @IsaacOpperman could you please share your table and data in https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2bde6876daf1738c1580b33b9e030d8d

Comment: @IsaacOpperman answer edited check now  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae3c60065009cf71a6ab4bb889cf4b78

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(*) AS challenges_created,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) cnt
    FROM Sample0.Hackers as h
    LEFT JOIN Sample0.Challenges c
        ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
    GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
)

SELECT
    hacker_id,
    name,
    challenges_created
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1 OR cnt = 1;
```

The idea here is that an aggregate record should be retained if it either is tied for the highest challenge count or there are no other records having the same challenge count.

Comment: I would handle it using window functions as well.

Comment: @Gordon Then it sounds like we'd both have a good _handle_ on this question LOL ^ ^.